# Question about double integration and change of variables

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem: I need to integrate
\begin{equation}
\int \int_D (x^2+y^2)dA
\end{equation}
Over the region bounded by the curves
\begin{align}
x^2-y^2=\pm1 \\
xy=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
In the positive quadrant of the $xy$ plane

Using the transformation $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=xy$ I want to find $x=h(u,v)$ and $y=g(u,v)$ and then integrate over a simpler region. So, first
\begin{align}
x^2-\frac{v^2}{x^2}=u \\
\Rightarrow x^4-ux^4-v^2=0
\end{align}
Which yields four solutions. The one that has sense to me for $x$ to be positive is
\begin{equation}
x=\frac{\sqrt{u+\sqrt{u^2+4v^2}}}{\sqrt{2}}=h(u,v)
\end{equation}
Using the same logic, I end up with
\begin{equation}
y=\frac{\sqrt{-u^2+\sqrt{u^4+4v^2}}}{\sqrt{2}}=g(u,v)
\end{equation}
But when trying to calculate the Jacobian of the transformation, this just complicates more the problem. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do polar coordinates behave better?

Comment: I haven't really tried, since the problem gave me the hint to use these transformations

Comment: Fair enough.  I misread your hyperbola as the unit circle so it was a poor suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation you are trying is

$$\iint_D x^2+y^2\mathrm d(x,y) ~{= \iint_D (x(u,v)^2+y(u,v)^2){\mathsf J_{(u,v)}^{(x,y)}}\mathrm d (u,v) }$$

Where $\mathsf J_{(u,v)}^{(x,y)} = \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial \big(x(u,v),y(u,v)\big)}{\partial (u,v)}\end{Vmatrix}$

And that is okay.... but complicated.   Try another angle of attack.

---

Recall that $\mathsf J_{(u,v)}^{(x,y)} ={\mathsf J^{(u,v)}_{(x,y)}}^{-1}$

And since we have: $\mathsf J_{(x,y)}^{(u,v)}~{=\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\end{Vmatrix} \\= \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial \big(x^2-y^2,xy\big)}{\partial (x,y)}\end{Vmatrix} \\= 2(x^2+y^2)} \\  $

Therefore we have:

$$\iint_D x^2+y^2\mathrm d(x,y) ~{= \iint_D (x^2+y^2){\mathsf J_{(u,v)}^{(x,y)}}\mathrm d (u,v) \\ = \iint_D \tfrac 12\mathrm d (u,v) \\ \vdots}$$

Comment: Thanks! So the answer is $1/2$? I really ignored the fact that $\mathsf J_{(u,v)}^{(x,y)} ={\mathsf J^{(u,v)}_{(x,y)}}^{-1}$... I never revised this in my calculus class sadly...

Answer (score 1):

Use the change the variables formula for a double integral: 
$$
\iint_D f(x,y)dA = \iint_R f(x(u,v),y(u,v))\Bigg| \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \Bigg| dudv, 
$$
where 
$$
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} 
= 
\det \begin{pmatrix}
x_u & x_v \\ 
y_u & y_v \\ 
\end{pmatrix} = x_u y_v-x_v y_u, 
$$
the Jacobian of the transformation. 
So let $u=x^2-y^2$ and let $v=xy$. Then since 
$$
\left( \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}  \right)^{-1} 
= \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} 
= \det \pmatrix{u_x & u_y\\ v_x & v_y } = u_xv_y - u_yv_x, 
$$ 
we have 
$$
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} 
= \det \pmatrix{2x & -2y \\ y & x} = 2x^2+2y^2 = 2\left(x^2+y^2\right).
$$
Note that 
\begin{align*}
\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2 &= x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4 \\ 
&= x^4 + 4x^2y^2 - 2x^2 y^2 + y^4  \\ 
&= x^4- 2x^2 y^2+y^4 +4x^2y^2   \\ 
&=\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2 +4 (xy)^2 \\ 
&= u^2 + 4v^2.  
\end{align*}
So $x^2 + y^2 = \sqrt{u^2 + 4v^2}$.

So 
\begin{align*}
\iint_D \left( x^2+ y^2 \right) dA 
&=  \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{u^2 + 4v^2} \left|\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u^2 + 4v^2}}\right|dudv \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-1}^{1}  dudv \\
& = \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{align*}